# Why is IIS blocking my requests to external APIs?

Tags: php, python, iis, python-requests, windows-server-2016

I'm using IIS on Windows Server 2016. I'm unable to use, for example, Python's `request.get()` and PHP's `curl` or `get_file_contents` when deployed in IIS. It returns error 500 after reaching the timeout period.

Everything works fine outside IIS, so it's **definitely something related with IIS**.

This just started to happen after I installed some windows updates, but, as far as I know, none of them were related with the IIS.

Comment: take a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/639887/iis-permissions-to-allow-outgoing-rest-http-requests-from-site-code

Comment: Try that but still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to use postman or browser to connect to the api in the IIS's server? Do you have the special proxy server setting in your sever? It means your server should use proxy to access the internet.

Comment: Problem solved. It appears that the sys adm did something and didn't say anything.